# Specifying dtypes for read_sql in pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, mysql-python

I would like to specify the dtypes returned when doing pandas.read_sql.  In particular I am interested in saving memory and having float values returned as np.float32 instead of np.float64.  I know that I can convert afterwards with astype(np.float32) but that doesn't solve the problem of the large memory requirements in the initial query.  In my actual code, I will be pulling 84 million rows, not the 5 shown here.  pandas.read_csv allows for specifying dtypes as a dict, but I see no way to do that with read_sql.

I am using MySQLdb and Python 2.7.

As an aside, read_sql seems to use far more memory while running (about 2x) than it needs for the final DataFrame storage.

```
In [70]: df=pd.read_sql('select ARP, ACP from train where seq < 5', connection)

In [71]: df
Out[71]: 
   ARP      ACP
0  1.17915  1.42595
1  1.10578  1.21369
2  1.35629  1.12693
3  1.56740  1.61847
4  1.28060  1.05935


In [72]: df.dtypes
Out[72]: 
ARP    float64
ACP    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: That would also be good in order to avoid conversion of integer column to floats whenever you have NaNs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use pandas [read_sql_query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html) which allows you to specify the returned dtypes (supported only since pandas 1.3).

```py
pd.read_sql_query('select ARP, ACP from train where seq < 5', connection,
                  dtype={'ARP': np.float32, 'ACP': np.float32})
```

Answer (score 7):

> As an aside, read_sql seems to use far more memory while running (about 2x) than it needs for the final DataFrame storage.

Maybe you can try our tool [ConnectorX](https://github.com/sfu-db/connector-x) (`pip install -U connectorx`), which is implemented in Rust and aims to improve the performance of `pandas.read_sql` in terms of both time and memory usage, and provides similar interface. To switch to it, you only need to:

```
import connectorx as cx
conn_url = "mysql://username:password@server:port/database"
query = "select ARP, ACP from train where seq < 5"
df = cx.read_sql(conn_url, query)
```

The reason `pandas.read_sql` uses a lot of memory during running is because of its large intermediate python objects, in `ConnectorX` we use Rust and stream process to tackle this problem.

Here is some benchmark result:

- PostgreSQL:
  [image: postgres memory]
- MySQL:
  [image: mysql memory]

Comment: Looks like a nice tool!

Comment: This tool is great. Querying ~5GB from my SQLite db ran @ 23 seconds using ConnectorX compared to the 91 seconds running on pd.read_sql

Answer (score 3):

What about cast() and convert()?

```
'SELECT cast(ARP as float32()), cast (ACP as float32()) from train where seq < 5'
```

or something similar.

http://www.smallsql.de/doc/sql-functions/system/convert.html

Comment: That is a very good suggestion, but I found 2 problems with it:
1. cast does not allow FLOAT (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html)
2. Even when trying DECIMAL(10,2), for example, the read_sql still returns float64 values.  How annoying is that?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look in [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6798) github issue, looks like they are inclined to add the option.

Answer (score 0):

CAST your data types in your SQL code. Python will adhere to the explicit data types in your SQL code. You can confirm this when doing df.info()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding @Ohad Bruker answer: It is since Pandas 2.0.0 also possbile to define dtype directly in read_sql.

Could be added as a comment to the answer but i am not authorized yet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35205994)